# Delete files in Edit view

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-core-2.0

In my application I try to delete single files from Edit view. It works ok, but doesn't refresh a site.
Item in FileDetails Class contains Id, Extension, FileName and TicketId(which is connected with Ticket class)

My code:

[Method in Controller](https://pastebin.com/A0wp03r2)

```
@section Scripts {

<script>
    $('.deleteItem').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $ctrl = $(this);
        if (confirm('Do you really want to delete this file?')) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("DeleteFile")',
                type: 'POST',
                data: { id: $(this).data('id') }
            }).done(function (data) {
                if (data.Result == "OK") {
                    $ctrl.closest('li').remove();
                }
                else if (data.Result.Message) {
                    alert(data.Result.Message);
                }
            }).fail(function () {
                alert("There is something wrong. Please try again.");
            })

        }
    });
</script>
}

<div class="form-group">
 <div class="col-md-10">
  <p>Upload one or more files</p>
   <input type="file" name="file" multiple />
  </div>
 <ul class="attachment">
   @foreach (var item in Model.Ticket.FileDetails)
    {
     <li>
   <a class="title" href="/Tickets/Download/?fileName=@(item.Id + item.Extension)&ticketId=@item.TicketId">@item.FileName</a>
   <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-id="@item.Id" class="deleteItem">X</a>
    </li>
   }
 </ul>
```

I get TypeError: data.Result is undefined

Answer (score 0):

Check your data variable before getting its Result property. Your data should be available in data.